# Excel Date Format To Timestamp in DB2 SQL

Tags: db2

I have an Excel extract that is loading dates into a table that are not a consistent format, making it more challenging to convert to a timestamp when we copy it into another table.

Example dates are:

1. 5/1/2015
2. 5/15/2015
3. 12/1/2015
4. 12/15/2015

I need to convert this to a timestamp format. To start, I am just trying to parse and concatenate the date into a character type formatted like a timestamp.

The timestamp format needs to be: `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS`

Our DB2 instance is very old and does not accept the following functions:
`INSTR`, `LOCATE_IN_STRING`

However, it does accept: `LOCATE`

I had the code working for 2 of the 4 date formats because I specified actual numbers in the parameters instead of using functions that could handle the different date formats. After modifying the query, in a poorly displayed table, my results are:

OLD DATE -- NEW DATE

4/3/2015 --  2015-04-3/ 00:00:00

3/30/2015 -- 2015-03-30 00:00:00

12/31/2015  --  2015-01-/3 00:00:00

12/3/2015 -- 2015-01-/3 00:00:00

The "--" in my table above indicate different columns in the table.

My current code is:

```
SELECT
STARTDATE
, RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(STARTDATE)), 4)     --YEAR
|| '-'
|| RIGHT('00' || SUBSTR(STARTDATE, 1, LOCATE(STARTDATE, '/', 1)+1), 2)  --MONTH
|| '-'
|| LEFT(SUBSTR(STARTDATE, 3, LOCATE(STARTDATE, '/', 1)+2) || '00', 2)   --DAY
|| ' 00:00:00' AS STARTDATE
FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1
```

Can anyone help?

Information about our DB2 version:

- DB2/NT SQL08016
- IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.13.127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish taking dates of CHAR data type from multiple date formats into the timestamp data type, all that was needed was:

SELECT TIMESTAMP(STARTDATE, "00:00:00")
FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to make the DB2 `IMPORT` or `LOAD` command do the date format conversion. In the table you're loading the file into, define the corresponding column to have the `DATE` data type, then issue a DB2 command like this:

```
import from yourfile of del modified by dateformat="MM/DD/YYYY" 
   replace into yourtable (column1, column2, ...);
```

After that the value will be a `DATE` -- that is how you should store dates anyway, not as character strings, -- and you can format it to your liking using the `VARCHAR_FORMAT()` function.

Comment: I get an error: In the filetmod a user specified format "DATEFORMAT" beginning with the string "'MM/DD/YYYY'" is not valid.

The code I have is using IMPORT syntax using "METHOD P."

Comment: Show the exact command that you used. Did you use single quotes around the format? Also, you may want to change that to `"M/D/YYYY"` to account for single-digit values.

Comment: I changed it to double quotes and I got no errors, but the date came out in the same formats that was a mixture of MM/DD/YYY and M/DD/YYYY and M/D/YYYY. This is due to leading zeros that being included in the date. The import into our temporary table will be copied into a field with the data type of TIMESTAMP. Is there a way to change it straight to a Timestamp?

Comment: TIMESTAMP(STARTDATE, '00:00:00') accomplished what we needed!

Comment: All that extra code was unneeded. I had tried other functions related to TIMESTAMP but got errors, so that is how I missed this. Thanks for your help though! I learned something new about the IMPORT command on DB2.

Comment: Datetime data types do not have any inherent format, as they are just numbers. Formatting takes place at the client, so the client locale settings or other parameters control how the values are shown.